# How can I keep my listview items from moving positions when an item is removed? - Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

So my problem is that when one of my items is removed from the listview, the rest of the items are no longer in the correct positions. For example when position 0 is removed, the item in position 1 moves to position 0. Causing it to open the activity rather than make a toast. If anybody has any simple solution that would be awesome. Thanks!

```
if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {

 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kendall_house, container, false);
 final ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.kendallBarList);


 final String[] barChallenges = new String[] {
  "Stand in the yard",
  "Look Up",
  "Eat Snow"
 };



 final List < String > barChallengesList = new ArrayList < String > (Arrays.asList(barChallenges));


 final ArrayAdapter < String > listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
  (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, barChallengesList);

 listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

 mDatabaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      if (dataSnapshot.child("kendallHouseCh1").exists()) {


       barChallengesList.remove("Stand in the yard");

       listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {



         if (position == 0) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), kendallHouseCH1.class);
          startActivity(intent);


         } else if (position == 1) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gross you ate it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


         } else if (position == 2) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "What do you see?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


         }
        }
       });
```

Comment: if you are removing, then don't do actions against position, instead use any data from your row to recognize the item e.g `id`

Comment: add a flag for every item

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How could I remove a list item without doing any actions against the position? Could you show an example? I also have no idea how to flag an item, or even what that is. Sorry, I am fairly new to this.

Comment: @Nate don't make your action dependent on the position, Make custom Bean Class instead of String list and associate action in bean class than check if action is this, do this

Comment: Does anybody know of any good tutorials for doing this?